# iOS any SDK or api of net banking for india

Tags: ios, iphone, payment

I need any link that provide API of net banking of all possible banks of india.
After researching a lot I found many providers like PayUbiz, Payway etc. But they provide api for PHP etc. Instead of embedding them in web View I want specific for iOS platform.

Thanks for any input very much in advance.

Comment: Why not using Paypal?

Comment: Have already implemented PayPal. Curious about other net banking feature that also provided by my Airtel and Paytm.

Comment: did you find some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCAvenue's mobile SDK solved my problem. It has many features, one of its feature has net banking of all possible banks of india. To download sdk you should have CCAvenue's merchant account.
[source](http://www.ccavenue.com/inapp_payments.jsp)
[image]